# Regex for splitting a string to get operators

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split, operators

I have a String = A+B+CC-D0.
I want to use a regular expression to split it apart to get an array of of the ops {+,+,-}

I have tried the regular expression:

```
"[^+-]"
```

But the output gave me a array of { ,+,+, ,+}, why?

```
    String s1 = "A+B+C-D";
    String s2 = "A0+B0";
    String[] op1 = s1.split([^+-]);
    String[] op2 = s2.split([^+-]);
    for(int i = 0; op1.length; i++){
        System.out.println(op1[i]);
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
Output of op1:
""
"+"
"+"
""
"-"

Output of op2:
""
""
"+"
```

Comment: just remove the empty elements from the array.

Comment: Yes I could, but then I need extra computations

Comment: Instead of splitting you could start matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all the characters other than operators with empty string then split the resultant string according to the boundary which exists between two operators.

```
String s1 = "A+B+C-D";
String[] op1 = s1.replaceAll("[^+-]","").split("(?<=.)(?=.)");
for(String i: op1){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output:

```
+
+
-
```

- `(?<=.)` positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a character.
- `(?=.)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a character.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what `split("(?<=.)(?=.)")` is doing exactly. It's quite cryptic. Still +1 because this works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you're splitting on single character, that is not `+` or `-`. When you split a string - `ABC`, it will get split 3 times - on `A`, `B` and `C` respectively, and hence you'll get an array - `["", "", "", ""]`.

To avoid this issue, use quantifier on regex:

```
String s1 = "A+B+C-D";
String s2 = "A0+B0";
String[] op1 = s1.split("[^+-]+");
String[] op2 = s2.split("[^+-]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(op1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(op2));
```

this is splitting on `"[^+-]+"`.

Now to remove the empty element at the beginning of array, you've to get rid of first delimiter from string, using `replaceFirst()` may be:

```
String[] op1 = s1.replaceFirst("[^+-]+", "").split("[^+-]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(op1)); // [+, +, -]
```

Comment: I don't think it's fixed in Java 8. I just tried it. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: this also gives me an extra empty element.

Comment: Yes I'm running java 8 and there is still a blank in the array

Comment: @peter.petrov Yup, haven't been fixed. I guess I updated the fix in wrong answer. :(

Comment: It has been fixed (or "fixed" is not the right word since this behaviour is expected, "improved" is better word) in Java 8 but only for zero-width delimiters, like `""` or look-around.